# Using Results Data From Connected (MySQL) Database in Visual Studio in relevant C++ Program

Tags: c++, mysql, database, visual-studio, integration

I'll keep this brief. I'm currently an intern, and the company I work for holds all of it's manufacturing batch history on a MySQL database. I have downloaded Microsoft Visual Studio 2017, and connected to the database successfully. I then began a new query within a .sql file within Microsoft Visual Studio.

While I can execute the code I have written in the .sql file, and get the results under the "Results" tab that I desire to use in my C++ program, I do not know how to call and execute the .sql query from my C++ program, and then use that data (that is under the "Results" tab) in my C++ program for further processing.

Below is the very basic, simple code that I have so far in my .cpp file to give you an idea of what I'm shooting for:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

        //Execute the SQL query file here, receive results for further processing below

        return 0;
    }
```

And below is the simple code I have written in the .sql file to execure a query:

```
    SELECT category, occurTime, sourceKeyName, recipe, "value",    formulaName, startTime, endTime , BatchID

    FROM dbo.Batch
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BatchHeader ON Batch.uniqueBatchID = BatchHeader.uniqueBatchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeHeader ON BatchHeader.uniqueBatchID = RecipeHeader.uniqueBatchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.BReportEvent ON RecipeHeader.uniqueBatchID = BReportEvent.uniqueBatchID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.RecipeFormula ON BReportEvent.uniqueBatchID = RecipeFormula.uniqueBatchID

    WHERE category = 'L-FAIL-MSG' 
       AND occurTime  >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
       AND "value" != ' '
```

The SQL program works and gives me the results I need. How can I execute it from my C++ Program (Both files are in Visual Studio and the database is linked with Visual Studio), and then use that data that is the result in my C++ Program for processing?

Comment: As it stands now your question is too broad. Use the appropriate libraries. Then use the appropriate methods from these libraries.

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope for this site. You're basically asking someone to write you a tutorial on database programming in C++ using Visual Studio and MySQL.

Comment: Then allow me to be extremely specific. What is the simplest way (command, or function) for me to tell my desktop to execute the .sql program file I have written from the C++ program I am writing?

Comment: @TitanUcheze:  All depends on the library you are using.  MySQL has the C++ connector.  There are other libraries that assist with connecting to a MySQL server using C++.